# Error when deploying tomcat app on aws elastic beanstalk via aws eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, amazon-web-services, tomcat, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I m using eclipse and aws plugin to deploy an Tomcat app on Elasticbeansalk. So far I was able to deploy it without problems. 
Today, I added a new profile on aws credentials and set it to default. I dont know if it s a coincidence but after that, Eclipse started giving the following error when starting deployment:

```
"Could not publish to the server.
Unable to create web application archive: No such file or directory"
```

I m not sure if it s because of Eclipse or AWS. I can still deploy it on my locahost without issues.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the new profile and credentials are not setup in your machine to match the new default profile.